# How can Use IN Operator In Jquery Or Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
RatecardIDs=[2, 22, 23, 25];
 if (parseInt(cellValue) in (RatecardIDs)) {
}
```

How I can use In operator in if condition.
in this code firs time it will execute code in if block then it is executing false block.

Comment: use [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) - `if(RatecardIDs.indexOf(parseInt(cellValue)) > -1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `in` operator in javascript is for key's in objects.

You can use `Array.indexOf()` to check if an element exists in the array, it will return `-1` if it doesn't exist

Now,

You can check `if(RatecardIDs.indexOf(parseInt(cellValue))>-1) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `in` operator used to get `keys`  in an object. You can use javascript's `Array.indexOf` or jquery's `inArray` for that.

Just use like bellow

```
RatecardIDs=[2, 22, 23, 25];

if(RatecardIDs.indexOf(parseInt(cellValue))>-1){
 ...
}
```

Or using jquery

```
if($.inArray(parseInt(cellValue),RatecardsId)>-1){
  ....
}
```

Comment: @ChiragSutariya I don't see a problem in that answer, where is the problem.